# Mysql query NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

My search for suggested files works fine. However, I would like to exclude one file from this search, but don't know how to add it to this query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT *, MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword') 
FROM `uploaded` 
WHERE MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword') 
OR file_name_keyword REGEXP '.*($file_name_keyword).*' LIMIT 8");
```

this `AND id NOT IN (57)`

I tried almost everything but it still does not exclude row at id 57.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your existing criteria in parentheses and then add the `NOT IN` at the end of the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *,MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword') 
FROM `uploaded` 
WHERE (MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword') OR file_name_keyword REGEXP '.*($file_name_keyword).*' )
AND id NOT IN (57)
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: Thanks, well formatted and explained. Will choose as best and faster answer.

Comment: It is good to mention that it is faster to check first the ID exclusion instead of checking the MATCH for the 57 row.

Comment: @PlamenNikolov what are you basing that on? For this query the order of the WHERE clause should make absolutely no performance difference.

Comment: @Ike Walker You are right, the optimizer should made this for you in most cases. Just mention it as a good practice.

Comment: @PlamenNikolov I think `WHERE <a> AND <b>` will *always* perform the same as `WHERE <b> AND <a>` so in this case worrying about the order is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT *, MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword') FROM `uploaded` 
WHERE 
    (MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword') 
OR  file_name_keyword REGEXP '.*($file_name_keyword).*') 
AND id NOT IN (57)
LIMIT 8
");
```

You need to use parenthesis around the OR condition otherwise mysql would read it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, 
            "SELECT *, MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword') 
             FROM `uploaded` 
             WHERE 
               id NOT IN (57) 
               AND (
                 MATCH(file_name_keyword) AGAINST('$file_name_keyword') 
                 OR 
                 file_name_keyword REGEXP '.*($file_name_keyword).*'
               ) 
             LIMIT 8");
```